# Angular 2 page not found when refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, typescript, npm

I have a problem, i push my project on production with the function `enableProdMode()` and i have a multiple component and i create my routes

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'formations', component: FormationComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

So, i `npm start` to launch my application on local and when i finish my developpement, i copy and push on my website. My application it's ok, i can change page dynamically whith my routes BUT if i refresh my page, for exemple in '/formations', my browser say 404 not found.
My question is : It's possibility to have my page view with not VPS or Dedicated server and i'm obligated to launch my application with `npm start` ?

Thanks you

Comment: `npm start` is for development purpose only.  you need to build it. for ex `ng build`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first error is simply because you don't have an empty / route defined.

The second is unrelated to angular. When you visit the localhost:14367/crisis-center url for the first time, angular has no chance to get involved because the request goes to your server first - you need to fix it there.

Please visit the gitter channel for support related questions in the future. Thanks!